# Shortcode function returning outside of div PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've created a shortcode for a custom menu in Wordpress.

The problem is that my $menu is showing up above and outside of the side-nav and side-nav-menu divs.

I've tried just echoing/returning it without storing it in $var and I get the same issue.

Am I missing something?

```
function custom_menu() {
   $menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'product-menu' ) );
   $var = '<div class="side-nav">
   <div class="side-nav-menu product-    nav">
   <p>Products</p>' . $menu . '
   </div></div>';
      return $var;
 }
 add_shortcode("custom", "custom_menu");
```

Comment: @dingo_d Thanks for your reply. I tried the edit below and it broke. Would I add it like this within the concatetation? '.wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'product-menu' ).'
add_shortcode("custom", "custom_menu");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wp_nav_menu()` echos its output to screen, and this is what is causing your issue in your shortcode. As you know, echoing anything inside a shortcode have unexpected output. `wp_nav_menu()` has a parameter called `echo` which is set to true bu default. You can just add

```
'echo' => false,
```

to your array of `wp_nav_menu`  arguments and that should solve your issue

Comment: Simple and much better then output buffering. @EmmaHarris If this solved the problem, then please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/270140) to close the question.

Comment: Thanks for comment @birgire

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the `wp_nav_menu()` echoes by default, so to store it in a variable you can do like you'd do with the regular widgets - output buffering:

```
function custom_menu() {
    ob_start();
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'product-menu' ) );
    $menu = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $var = '<div class="side-nav">
   <div class="side-nav-menu product-    nav">
   <p>Products</p>' . $menu . '
   </div></div>';
      return $var;

 }
 add_shortcode("custom", "custom_menu");
```

This should work.

What you are doing is start the output buffer with `ob_start();`, then everything you echo inside is caught in the buffer, then you output the contents of the buffer in the `$menu` variable, and clean the buffer. Then you can safely use the `$menu` variable as you wish

Comment: Only use output buffering as **last** resort. You only need to set the `echo` parameter to false

Comment: If Pieter says that you should use it as a last resort, then do his method instead, he knows what he's saying :)

Comment: It is still quite valid and a valid alternative way to do things, specially if there is no other build in work-around for something. Just in this case, you are doing a lot of unnecessary work which does influence performance. :-)